# Getting Service Fabric Parameters Into Angular Application

Tags: angular, azure, azure-service-fabric

I'm looking for a way to read in a parameter from service fabric into my angular 2 application. For example I want to be able to set the api endpoint and environment name (to display what environment we are on) based on the values in the service fabric parameter config xml files. I haven't found a simple and elegant solution to this problem yet.

My current workaround involves using an Asp.Net controller that serves the static angular to set the values from the angular config into the ViewBag object.

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var apiUrl = _configurationPackage.Settings.Sections["Spa_Configuration"].Parameters["apiUrl"].Value;
        var environmentName = _configurationPackage.Settings.Sections["Spa_Configuration"].Parameters["environmentName"].Value;

        ViewBag.apiUrl = apiUrl;
        ViewBag.environmentName = environmentName;

        return View();
    }
```

I then add these values to the session storage by calling a javascript function on window.onload in Index.cshtml.

```
<script>
  function codeAddress() {

    var environmentName = '@ViewBag.environmentName';
    var myJsVariable = '@ViewBag.apiUrl';

    console.log(environmentName);

    sessionStorage.setItem('apiUrl', myJsVariable);
    sessionStorage.setItem('environmentName', environmentName);

    console.log(sessionStorage);
  }

  window.onload = codeAddress;
</script>
```

I then consume these variables in my angular controller like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

  constructor(private _httpClient: HttpClient, private _http: Http) { }

  private baseUrl = sessionStorage.getItem('apiUrl');
```

This approach seems to work up to a point. The problem is that when the app loads both environmentName and the apiUrl don't seem to have set correctly. Only when I hit refresh do these seem to get set and the app works as expected.

Another issue with this approach is that every time I build the angular app I have to manually enter the polyfill, inline main etc. js files into the Index.cshtml file which is ab it of a pain and doesn't seem like the correct way to approach the problem.

So does anyone have any idea what I have done wrong here. It doesn't really feel like I have taken the right approach so any advice on alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Moving my codeAddress function into the head of Index.cshtml seems to have solved my need to refresh problem. However this approach still feels incorrect and any other solutions or ideas on how to solve this problem would be appreciated.